# Adapter not working

Tags: android, adapter

In my `OncreateView()` set the adapter which is working when i am first loading the page. When i go to another page and make changes then come back to this fragment it is not working `adapter.notifyDatasetchanged()`.

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    groupItem.clear();
    childItem.clear();
    List<String> child_Category;child_Category=new ArrayList<String>();
    groupItem = obj_Listdatabase.fetchcategory();
    childItem.clear();
    ListIterator<String> iterator = groupItem
            .listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String categoryname = iterator.next();
        child_Category = new ArrayList<String>();
        child_Category = obj_Listdatabase
                .fetchchildlist(categoryname);
        childItem.add(child_Category);
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: does the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); not work, or is it not getting called? can you put a breakpoint/log there and see if it is at all called?

Comment: when i am adding this                                         adapter = new CategoryExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), groupItem,
                childItem);
        expandlistview.setAdapter(adapter);  instead of adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); which is working correctly...

Comment: not call the BaseExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: When i back from another fragment to this fragment the adapter not refreshed and give empty expandable listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hai I got output for this one:

```
    groupItem.addAll(obj_Listdatabase.fetchcategory());
```

Instead of This

```
   //groupItem = obj_Listdatabase.fetchcategory();
```

> Because i change the reference in assignment statement(=) for that adapter.So i use addAll() method to store the values only instead of reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should reaaaally indent your code more cleanly, never use several ";" on the same line for example. 
And you can definitely use BaseExpandableListAdapter the issu is somewhere else..

You should also notice that onCreate view is more suitable for "creating view" so all the adapter stuff should be somewhere else like onViewCreated, or onActivityCreated as you need (it's just some advices)

---

I assume your adapter is in a Fragment since you use **GetActivity()** and in the constructor of your adapter you pass a reference to the activity (context), the group list and the child list.. ok

we ll assume that you are using the fragment onStart. From the official doc :

```
Called when the Fragment is visible to the user. This is generally tied to Activity.onStart of the containing Activity's lifecycle.
```

So normally this method is called after onViewCreate, onViewCreated .. etc at least the first time you code is running. So this is ok

Did you try using **adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidate()** and then do **adapter.notidyDataSetChanged** ?

---

One last thing, since you actually pass the data to your adapter by the constructor, when you update your lists **how can the adapter be aware of the changes ?** Are your lists global (static) ?

If not, before doing adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() you should pass the lists (group and child) to the adapter with some setter..

good luck